# Move Modern UI page from on Subsite to another subsite

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages, sitepages

Is there any way so I can move MUI pages from one location to another with contents.

I have used all OOB webpart to create MUI page now I have to move to another site do i need to create again or is there any way to move.

Comment: You can use "Copy to" functionality in classic experience to copy pages from on site to another. check [this](https://sharepointmaven.com/copy-pages-sharepoint-online/) and let me know if it helps you.

Comment: yes it helped thank you

Comment: Great, I have written it as an answer below. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy pages from one subsite to another in SharePoint classic experience. So you may need to switch to classic experience and then switch back to modern experience after copying the pages.

Follow below steps:

1. Go to Site Pages library.
2. Select ellipses (three dots) next to page name.
3. Select **Copy** option.
4. Enter destination library URL and name of page.
5. Click Ok

**Reference**: [How to copy pages in SharePoint Online](https://sharepointmaven.com/copy-pages-sharepoint-online/)

Alternatively you can use **Site Content and Structure** as well. But, it is is now available only to **site collection administrators**.

Site and Content Structure URL: `SiteUrl/_layouts/15/sitemanager.aspx`

Answer (score 0):

You can move Modern UI page from on Subsite to another subsite using Site Content and Structure.

You can navigate to the following url to access to Site Content and Structure page in SharePoint online.

http(s)://YourSiteURL/_layouts/15/sitemanager.aspx

SharePoint Online: Moving items between lists for your reference:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51449.sharepoint-online-moving-items-between-lists.aspx